# How do I access a network drive that won't upgrade past SMBv1 w/ devices that have been Updated to SMBv2 & v3?

Tags: smb

I am getting Network drive error code 0x80070035 because the network drive is no longer being updated or supported by the manufacturer.

I still want to use the drive since its a good drive, but I don't want to roll back all the connections the workstations to before SMB v2 or v3

How do I only have that connection (from workstation to older network drive) be v1 while keeping everything else v2 & v3?

Could there be other possible deeper issues that might be triggering this as a false positive?

Comment: apologies I shouldn't have left it with just a vague implication. 

I can choose to roll back to a prior version of MS update or disable all of SMB 2&3 entirely (not secure), but I am trying to see if there is a way to make only that connection in the local IP default to SMBv1

This is still related enough to security I would think that I could ask it here.

Comment: Doing some search for [allow specific IP smbv1](https://www.google.com/search?q=allow+specific+IP+smbv1&oq=allow+specific+IP+smbv1) I get [firewall rules to allow smb1 to specific IP addresses??](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6cdee681-7f92-4562-be36-539f458fda58/firewall-rules-to-allow-smb1-to-specific-ip-addresses?forum=winserverNIS) as the first hit which seems to answer your problem, i.e. enable smbv1 but restrict who you can connect to with it. There does not seem to be a way to enable it only for connecting to specific IP addresses.